# How to reference style tag element in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

When creating a Single Page Application, I have had the need to reuse CSS as a string.
The need was from a library requiring passing CSS as a string and needing to also use that CSS in the page.
To achieve this, I went through 2 routes, and both failed. Referring to the style tag element should be simple, so I'll focus on this in this issue, but if anyone can solve the other route, please let me know. Regards.

Attempted routes to solve issue:

- Reference style tag element. Couldn't get this to work. Even has problems using global querying because of build process destroying ids.
- I tried using raw-loader to directly import, but failed. I am using Typescript so tried to import as a string but failed again.

Comment: Have you considered using [v-html](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)?

Comment: @B.Fleming You mean inputting the style tag as v-html(raw HTML)? Wouldn't that remove the ability for functionality such as scoped and Vue.js optimizations?
I was actually expecting Vue.js to support something like vueInstance.$refs.styles[0].

Comment: If you want to have dynamic styles from a string, then there really aren't many options available to you. You can either use `v-html` to insert a raw `style` tag with your CSS rules enclosed, or you can find a way to parse the string if you can be sure of what it will contain and use [class and style bindings](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to achieve this. The latter would be more performant, but far more restrictive and likely more prone to errors. The entire requirement of needing to use an arbitrary CSS string that needs to be interpreted imposes a huge limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my main goal of reusing the same CSS by using external css in the style tag and importing the css as a string using raw-loader.

```
import css from !!raw-loader!./my-css.css
...
<style src="./my-css.css">
```

I still do not know how to get a safe reference to the style tag, but the above solves my issue.
* The reason for the style tag not being easily referenced even via document.querySelector is that the build process seems to strip attributes.